# jsPlumb delete on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im using jsPlumb plugin to make a drag and drop with connections flowchart, please have a look at the code below:

```
// delete connection when clicked //
 instance.bind("click", function(conn, originalEvent) {


            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the Connection?"))
            {
                instance.detach(conn);
                $.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   url: 'deleteConnection.php',
   data: ({appId: <?PHP echo $appId;?> , sourceId : conn.sourceId.substring(15) , targetId : conn.targetId.substring(15)})
    });
            }

        });
```

this code will listen to click on a connection and will delete the connection upon confirmation, what I would like to do is the same procedure but for the dragable items that Im connection to each other, I need to listen to clicks on the dragable item and upon confirmation to delete it with all its endpoints and connections,

any help is really appreciated, thank you

Comment: Simply using jQuery `.remove()` on the selected object would do. It would delete the draggable object clicked on along with all endpoints and connections.

Comment: thank you, I have tried using jquery .remove and pass to it the id of the element, but it only deleted the element and left the endpoints as well as its connections hanged...